# Does the entropy $H(X+Y|Y) = H(X)$?

Tags: random-variables, information-theory, entropy

Suppose I have random variables $X, Y$ that are independent and identically distributed. If we denote the entropy by $H$, then does the following equality hold?

$$H(X+Y|Y) = H(X).$$

My intuition says yes since the only randomness in $X+Y$ that remains when $Y$ is observed is $X$. However, I struggle to prove this formally.

Comment: In general, $H(X+Y|X) = H(Y|X)$. If they are independent, then the equality follows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Background

We can use the relationship between $H(A|B)$ and $H(A|B=b)$. The latter is the entropy of $A$ conditioned on $B$ taking a particular value $b$

$$
H(A|B=b) = -\sum_a p(A=a|B=b) \log p(A=a|B=b)\tag1
$$

and the former is $H(A|B=b)$ averaged over all possible values of $B$

$$
H(A|B) = \sum_b p(B=b) H(A|B=b),\tag2
$$

see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy#Motivation) for the equivalence of $(2)$ to the other common definition of $H(A|B)$.

### Proof

The probability distribution of the random variable $X + y$ is the same as the probability distribution of $X+Y$ conditioned on $Y=y$, i.e.

$$
p(X+y=z) = p(X+Y=z|Y=y)
$$

for any fixed $z$. Therefore, $H(X+Y|Y=y) = H(X+y)$. Moreover, $H(X)$ depends on the probabilities assigned by $X$ to the different possible values, but does not depend on those values. Therefore, $H(X + y) = H(X)$ for any fixed $y$.

Using these two observations and equation $(2)$, we have

$$
\begin{align}
H(X+Y|Y) &= \sum_y p(Y=y) H(X+Y|Y=y) \\
&= \sum_y p(Y=y) H(X+y) \\
&= \sum_y p(Y=y) H(X) \\
&= H(X) \sum_y p(Y=y) \\
&= H(X).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! There is a minor typo in the first line of the proof, I tried to edit it but I could not since I needed to change at least 6 characters.